# NSFileManager copyItemAtPath complains about a nonexistent file that does exist

Tags: objective-c, file-io, nsfilemanager

I am trying to copy a file using `[[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath: toPath: error:]` but it is failing with the following error:

> 4: The file does not exist.

The relevant code is below, and the file does exist and the path string is correct because it is created beforehand with the exact same file path string.

```
NSFileManager* manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError* error;
NSString* fileName = [Sound getFileName:Title];
NSString* oldDirectory = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@/", [settings stringForKey:@"downloadFolder"], authorFolder];
NSString* oldFile = [oldDirectory stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@.mp3", fileName];
NSString* newFile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/iTunes/iTunes Media/Automatically Add to iTunes/%@.mp3", [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSMusicDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0], fileName];
BOOL result = [manager copyItemAtPath:oldFile toPath:newFile error:&error];
if (!result && error)
{
     NSLog(oldFile);
     NSLog(@"There was an error copying the file to the iTunes directory! %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

It's not the exact code, but all relevant code should be above. If I use `[manager fileExistsAtPath:oldFile]` the result is **YES**.

What could cause the copy to fail and say the file doesn't exist, even if it does?

**UPDATE:**

Issue fixed. Turns out the output folder was really Automatically Add to iTunes.localized, but I didn't notice this initially when just paging through the finder. Fixing the output path solved the issue! Thanks for the help.

Comment: Keep in mind that the `copyItemAtPath:toPath:error:` method will fail if the destination file already exists. It will not overwrite an existing file.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks for the heads up. I've corrected my code locally to check for this, but I have manually made sure that the destination file does not exist and still receive this error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If any of the directories in the path of the destination don't exist, you'll get a similar error to what you'd get if the source doesn't exist.  Check what `[manager fileExistsAtPath:[newFile stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] isDirectory:&isDir]` returns.

Comment: The result is NO for both isDir and the actual returned value. I would assume this means my issue lies in the output path. I'll look into it further and hopefully fix my issue on my own. Thank you for the heads up, I at least know where to look better now

Comment: Marked as answer because no correct answers were given, but this lead me to find the issue!

Comment: Thanks for accepting, but I'm confused why you say it wasn't correct. It sounds like I exactly predicted what was wrong.

Comment: I'm sorry I completely looked over your first sentence when typing my response. I meant that as in the actual issue was a misnamed directory, but you were right in pointing out the issue. My apologies, and thanks again for solving my issue!

Comment: Thank!  Eight years later and the copyItemAtPath method still gives the same misleading error.  If it's broke don't fix it! .... as they say.

Answer (score 3):

You're using the API wrong. You need to look at the return value of `-copyItemAtPath:toPath:error:`. Only if that returns `NO` does that mean an error occurred.

If you're using ARC, your `error` variable *should* be `nil` if no error occurred (although this isn't technically guaranteed), but if you're using MRR it probably won't, because you never initialized it.

Comment: I actually tried using the return value, and it is returning NO along with the error. It's also not actually copying the file so that's a pretty big indicator that it's not working.